Hardy-Littlewood circle method and ternary Goldbach under GRH
I am working on section 26 of Davenport's book on using the Hardy-Littlewood circle method to tackle the (weak) ternary Goldbach conjecture.
The idea is to divide the interval $[0,1]$ into major arcs $\mathfrak{M}$ and minor arcs $\mathfrak{m}$. Over the major arc, we use the Siegel-Walfisz theorem, and over the minor arc, we use Vinogradov's estimate of the exponential sum
$$
S(\alpha)=\sum_{k\le N}\Lambda(k)e(k\alpha).
$$
The standard way to estimate $S(\alpha)$ is based on the so-called Vaughan's identity, and it's a little technical. However, on this wikipedia page, it was mentioned that if we assume GRH (generalized Riemann hypothesis), then the argument used for the major arcs can be extended to the minor arcs.
Can anybody please elaborate on this?
My guess (following Davenport $\S$26): Without GRH, we let $\mathfrak{M}$ be the union of intervals centered at rational numbers $a/q$ with "small" denominator, namely $q\le(\log N)^B$, because we wanted to apply Siegel-Walfisz. If we had GRH, then probably we can let $q\le N^\varepsilon$, for some fixed $\varepsilon>0$? Then our estimate of major arcs still works, and on minor arcs we can probably use the Dirichlet approximation theorem again, and the same argument applies? Is this correct or necessary? Is there even a need to distinguish between "major" and "minor" arcs under GRH?
Any help/insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

For the prime number theorem in arithmetic progressions itself, Siegel–Walfisz allows us to handle moduli $q$ as large as a power of $\log N$, while GRH allows us to handle moduli as large as $\sqrt N$ (up to a logarithmic factor). I believe the same is true for the major arcs here.

@GregMartin Yes (actually GRH allows us to handle $q\le N$, but the estimate is trivial if $q>\sqrt{N}$). But we also need to consider the length of the interval in the major (minor) arcs. Without GRH, the length was taken to be $N^{-1}(\log N)^B$. With GRH, I'm not entirely sure what the length should be. Probably $N^{-1+\varepsilon}$ or $N^{-1/2}$? But then I'm worried about the minor arc.
